# How much heat (solar-energy) is required to evaporate water?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I was wondering how to calculate the mass of water that evaporates and the amount of energy it demands if I were to expose the water to the heat irradiate from the sun given by Q. Q=1360KJ/m^2 is the solar constant. I tried to use this specific heat eq Q= hm However this method lack the variables that I need and influence evaporation rate (such as humidity, water temp, surface area and more), I also tried Penman equation but I understand that the equation is suitable for agriculture areas and not for urban areas.

so are there alternatives to calculating this at lower temperatures where evaporation occurs?

I am aware that are similar posts about this topic, but there were no satisfactory answers in them.

Thank you!

Comment: Which similar posts?

Comment: Have you checked this site: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/evaporation-water-surface-d_690.html

Comment: How does the water know it's in an agricultural area and not an urban area? Also see [Nakamichi and Moroizumi, "Applicability of three complementary relationship models for estimating
actual evapotranspiration in urban area"](https://content.sciendo.com/downloadpdf/journals/johh/63/2/article-p117.xml).

Comment: @BobD yes I've tried this site, it doesn't give what  I want. I need to know how much water is evaporated and how much energy is used to do so only from the sun. while what you suggested is to calculate how much energy required to maintain a pool at certain temp

Comment: @Chemomechanics thank you, it looks useful but I'm not that good at thermodynamics could some one walk me through ?